# How to fix my firewall iptables in centos?

Tags: iptables

My task from uni is make me to install centoc and now im having problem with firewall iptables

here it says :
[image]

and here is the iptables
[image]

what should i do ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? When does the error in the first image appear?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when you can copy/paste text.  Search engines can't access screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

You used a capital `-P` on the 11th line (error message on the first screenshot):

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -P tcp --dport 50000 -j ACCEPT
                                     ^^
```

Replace the `-P` with `-p` and it should work.

Comment: oh my god, thankyou so much. now i finally know the reasons.

Comment: BTW, you can replace lines 11-13 with a single line by replacing each `--dport` with a combined `--dport 50000:50002`.